# iText 2 replace text in paragraph with different font

Tags: java, itext, paragraph

I am working with `iText`. I am building a simple "parser" for reading data from database(JSON) and a template(pdf structure) in XML to create a PDF dynamically. I want to change some words in paragraph with different font. 
For example if I had a paragraph with text  `"Hello world"`, I want to change the word `"world"` in bold or italic. Is this any way to do this with `iText2`.

```
**XML template:**
<paragraph type="italic" font="16"> Hello @@databaseParam</paragraph>
**Database value:**
{
"databaseParam":"world"
}
**Result:**
PDF with paragraph Hello world with all text italic and font 16
```

This is for moment what i did, i just need to change "world"(data read from db) with diffent font(maybe bold with 20 font).

Comment: Sorry for my bad understanding. Why can't you use a newer version of the iText library? Because the older version is actually _less secure_.

Comment: What is your current code for generating the result pdf? As your code shall be improved, we need enough of it fo start with.

Comment: Hi. I solved the problem. Thank you all for answering. Btw, I can't use the new version because my company used this version for many other projects (on backend servers), so they "force" me to manage all with this old version.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you found a solution it is custom to answer your own question to help others who got the same problem...